# Share class name between JavaScript and SASS with Webpack?

Tags: webpack

How can I share a class name as a variable between my JavaScript and SASS with Webpack?

Im already sharing an integer this way:

In my SASS:

```
$animationSpeed: 400;
:export {
  animationSpeed: $animationSpeed;
}
```

In my JS:

```
import styles from './styles.scss';
const animationSpeed = parseInt(styles.animationSpeed);
```

I can make the classname a variable with this in my SASS:

```
$animationClass: item--animating;
:export {
  animationClass: $animationClass;
}
.#{$animationClass} {
  // styles here
}
```

However this in my JS doenst work. I assume its because parseInt is for integers.

```
const animationClass = parseInt(styles.animationClass);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh! It was really simple:

```
$animationClass: item--animating;
:export {
  animationClass: $animationClass;
}
.#{$animationClass} {
  // styles here
}

import styles from './styles.scss';
const animationClass = styles.animationClass;
```